# Shifting divs down based on the visibility of the above section

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to work through Rob's intro to web development course on Udemy. One of his project is having us trying to replicate bbc.co.uk

On bbc.co.uk and many responsive website alike, when you press a section, it reveals a new section. For example, when you press "More" on BBC's top nav bar, it shows more options.

But what I can't figure out is how do you shift rest of the website downwards when you reveal more options so it aligns with the page. And when the additional options are not revealed, the rest of the page is right below the nav bar.

Thanks!

Comment: Have in mind that, in terms of performance, reflows are very expensive for the browser. You can read [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) for more info. The menu at bbc.co.uk should not be used as an example of a good design.

Comment: Thanks alot! Did not know that all.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're describing is simple box model behavior. By default, elements defined earlier in the DOM will affect position of elements that come after. So increasing height, padding, margin, or hiding/showing earlier elements on the page will affect and "push down" elements defined later. Here's a simple example.

```css
div {
  transition: padding .5s;
}
div:hover {
  padding: 0 0 5em;
}
```

```html
<div>hover me</div>
<div>this is some more content</div>
```

And here's another that hides/shows content

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
div:hover + .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>hover me</div>
<div class="hidden">hidden content</div>
<div>this is some more content</div>
```